# "module object is not callable" Error for ftp upload file on cpanel web server

Tags: python, cpanel, ftplib

i trying to send files via python to cpanl web server and at first time i create a ftp user then i use this code for uploading but raise the following error

python code :

```
import ftplib as FTP

ftp = FTP("ftp.example.com")
ftp.login (username='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', password="xxxxxxxx")
ftp.cwd('/home/example/public_html/img')

def image_ftp_send():

    filename = '1.jpg'
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+filename , open(file, 'rb'))
    ftp.quit()
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Image ftp", line 24, in <module>
    ftp = FTP("ftp.example.com")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callabl
```

Comment: Your import is incorrect.  Use `from ftplib import FTP`, this imports the class `FTP` rather than aliasing the `ftplib` module as `FTP`

Answer (score 0):

Below codes does not have the error you are getting.

```
import ftplib 
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.example.com')
ftp.login (username='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', password="xxxxxxxx")
ftp.cwd('/home/example/public_html/img')
```